# How can I return a json from c# but remove the response d:null

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net, webserver

how can I remove d:null from my service response?
I have tried many options and it continues to return the value d:null and I don't know what else can be done to solve the problem

I add my c# code, the configuration of my web.config and the response of the service, where you can see the correct response response:200 but it continues adding the value d:null

```
[WebMethod]
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]

        public void test(string numberDoc)
        {
            if (!inicializo) inicializa();
            string resp = "200";
            WebException webException = null;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Clear();
            // Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Response des = new Response();
            des.response = resp;


            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(des));
        }


<system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="DebugJSonBehavior" >
                    <enableWebScript />
                    <!--need set automaticFormatSelectionEnabled attribute -->
                    <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="DebugJSonBehavior" >
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
```

this is my response when i call the service from postman
{
"response": "200"
}{
"d": null
}

thanks

Comment: your json is not valid, post the real one

Comment: that is the response that postman gives me so I don't know what the real json is

Comment: Postman would never gave a  not valid json as a response, it is just impossible

Comment: I just responded including images with postman's response and the code

Answer (score 2):

this was my solution

```
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void test(string number)
        {
          
        
            WebException webException = null;

            var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            Resultres = new Result();
            res.response = "ok";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(js.Serialize(res));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: After 6 hr try and fail struggle, i found this answer fix the issue. - d:null. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With this code it returns me what you see in the image where d:null is added at the end of the response in postman

```
 [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void test(string numberDoc)
        {
            if (!inicializo) inicializa();
            string resp = "200";
            WebException webException = null;
       
            Context.Response.Clear();
            // Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Response des = new Response();
            des.response = resp;

            Response res = new Response();
            res.response = "Apple";
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
            Context.Response.Write(json);
        }
```

[image]

now returning a string postman keeps including the d in the response and I don't know how to remove d:

```
 [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string test(string numberDoc)
        {
            if (!inicializo) inicializa();
            string resp = "200";
            WebException webException = null;
       
            Context.Response.Clear();
            // Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Response des = new Response();
            des.response = resp;

            Response res = new Response();
            res.response = "Apple";
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
            return json;
            //Context.Response.Write(json);
        }
```

response postman
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

    public void Locations(string Location)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer Js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        
        Query = "Select xxxx";
        DataTable Dt = Func.GetDataTable(Query);

        if (Dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            LocationsCs Data = new LocationsCs();
            Data.Id = "0";
            Data.Location = "0";
            Context.Response.Write(Js.Serialize(Data));
        }
        else
        {
            List<LocationsCs> Locations = new List<LocationsCs>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Locations.Add(new LocationsCs
                {
                    Id = Dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString(),
                    Location = Dt.Rows[i]["Location"].ToString(),
                });
            }
            //string  strResponse = Js.Serialize(Data);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Js.Serialize(Locations));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }

    public class LocationsCs
    {
        public String Id;
        public String Location;
    }
```

this works for me.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?